# What the best poissible way to handle points in jsxgraph?

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

I am handling points by using calculating the vector and then label the points what's the best possible to handle it so that it doesn't overlap;
[Look at the image for more clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ym3MB.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, see https://jsfiddle.net/rLq8pgzo/ :

```
JXG.Options.label.autoPosition = true;
var pos = function() { return '(' + 
                          this.X().toFixed(1) + 
                          ',' + 
                          this.Y().toFixed(1) + ')'; };

var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', { 
       boundingbox: [-15, 15, 15, -15], 
       axis: true 
    });
var p1 = board.create('point', [-10, 2], {name: pos});
var p2 = board.create('point', [-5, 1], {name: pos});
var p3 = board.create('point', [-5, 2], {name: pos});
var p4 = board.create('point', [9, 4], {name: pos});
```

The attribute `autoPosition` is new and only available in the nightly builds, yet. Further, it seems to have some problems at the beginning if the label content is dynamic.